# How to style child component in a react styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, styling

I can't seem to style the inner child component `Product` to float left. I want to do this at upper parent level so the Product itself remains agnostic to position.

```
import React from 'react';
import Product from './product.js';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ProductContainer = styled.div`
 ${Product} {
  float: left;
 }
`


class ClassProductContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ProductContainer>
                <Product label="Item 1 £10" />
                <Product label="Item 1 £10" />
                <Product label="Item 1 £10" />
                <Product label="Item 1 £10" />
            </ProductContainer>
            )
        }
    }

export default ClassProductContainer;
```

I am using it like this in app.js

```
import Container from './components/container.js';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ClassProductContainer from './components/product-container.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
        <ClassProductContainer />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about this, `Product` component is still composed of different HTML elements right? So when you do:

```
 ${Product} {
  float: left;
 }
```

Exactly which HTML element are you setting the `float: left`?

---

One way you can handle this is, inside the `Product` component, find that exact HTML element you want to style, give it a className, then you can just replace the `${Product}` with `.whatever-class-name-you-set`.

But I think since the styling needs to be applied on `<Product>`, you should create the styled component on Product level.